# I want to apply a css for 3rd div tag based on whether the checkbox in first div tag is checked or not using css

Tags: css

I want to apply  css for 3rd div tag  based on whether the checkbox in first div tag is checked or not using css

Comment: Depending on your html structure, it can't be done, since that checkbox it's not sibling of the divs, it's a child of one div. Next time ask a correct question with a correct title and a correct body.

Comment: My code is like following  <div class="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/></div><div class="div2"><div class="div3>//some code</div></div>

Comment: I want center align div3 based on whether the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: As I tell you before, it can't be done with that code. It can be done with the checkbox outside the `div1`. If you can get out the checkbox I can help you. Otherwise you can't make it with CSS (maybe you can try Javascript)

Comment: Ok..I will try..thanks for the response

Comment: You are welcome, come back if you need help with my solution getting out the checkbox of the div1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in pure CSS with your current code structure, due to the fact that CSS doesn't have a `parent` selector. Without adjusting your HTML, you'd have to use a different language. The most common way to solve something like this is with jQuery. Assuming you have access to jQuery, the code would be:

```
if ($('input.checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $('.div3').css('text-align', 'center');
}
```

Also bear in mind that you're missing a `"` at the end of your div3 declaration ;)